# Shape data exchange via a connector

Tags: data-transfer, microsoft-visio-2010, shapes

I am already quite a time a VISIO user but this was merely as a graphic designer.
Since a few months I try to add data to my shapes and put some inteligence behind the shapes. I discovered lot of possibilities in the shapesheets and made some nice things but I want to go further.
Currently I am working on some drawing where different shapes ( with data underneath ) are placed ( taken from a stencil ) to make a kind of a machine configuration.  I can generate from that drawing a lot of usefull information via the reports.
Now my question ;
is there a way to exchange data between shapes by drawing a connection ( or with a intelligent connector ), by the event of 'both shapes are now connected'

eg : shape X ( a motor ) has prop.My_ID ( eg : motor_1 ) and prop.Conn_ID (empty)
        , shape Y ( a cabinet ) has prop.My_ID ( eg : cabinet_7) and prop.Conn_ID (empty)

If I now draw a connection between motor_1 and cabinet_7,  I would like to exchange the motor My_ID to the cabinet Conn_ID and the cabinet My_ID to the motor Conn_ID.
If I remove the connector , both Conn_ID's should become empty or 0..

- Is this feasible ?
- Can the making of a connection trigger events ?
- Can somebody point me in what direction I should start searching, 
  I do not expect to receive a complete solution , only some hints and tips because this is not an easy one I think.

Thanks already for any comments !
Peter

Answer (score 0):

Have alook at the events described here

1. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff766580.aspx
2. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff766015.aspx

Comment: The code that those links go to are for features added in Visio 2013. The OP's question isabout Visio 2010.

Answer (score -1):

I found a very helpfull article at the VISIO GUY forum ( april 2009 ) by David Edson. "Analyse connectivity between process flows"
[link](http://www.visguy.com/2009/04/22/analyze-connectivity-between-process-flows/)

This gives me a good start of how to investigate who is connected to whom and from there I get 2 names of sheets where I can exchange prop or user data.